# Why is LINQPad trying (and failing) to open ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff.htm#?

Tags: sql-server, dns, linqpad, ieframe.dll

When I execute a simple query in LINQPad (by mashing the green right arrow), I get this:

[image]

I can Export the data (to HTML, Excel, or Word), but still...

### UPDATE

Apparently it was a problem with Windows (7) and/or some internal network issue, because after rebooting and re-running, I can again see query results from right within LINQPad.

Comment: Does IE work correctly on your machine?

Comment: Yes, it works fine; I don't normally use it (using Chrome instead), but I just opened it, googled for "Linqpad" and went to your page - all seems fine with IE itself.